# replicating strategy three step binomial

Tags: options, option-pricing, replication

I am having some trouble setting up a replicating strategy for a call option with a three step binomial model (discrete).

I have no trouble doing this in a two step binomial model by backward recursion on time.

Any guidance on how to do this with a three step binomial model (discrete)?

Comment: Do you mean 3 or 2 periods? A 2-period model has 3 steps.

Comment: Where exactly do you have trouble? If I get your described correct  you find that you have to solve a linear equation with two unknowns but three equations? Is this correct?

Comment: Thank you. I think I understand. Just like with two steps but one more equation.